# Linq - Specified cast is not valid

Tags: c#, ado.net

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> drIEOrderDetail = 
   from data in dsOrder.Tables["ORDDETL02"].AsEnumerable()
   where data.Field<int>("INOWNER") == int.Parse(txtInventoryOwner.Text.Trim()).ToString()
   && data.Field<string>("SKUCODE") == txtSKUCode.Text.Trim()
   &&  data.Field<string>("PACKID") == cmbPackageId.SelectedValue.ToString()
   &&  data.Field<string>("BATCH") == txtBatch.Text.ToString()                                                           
   select data;
```

I'm getting error in:

```
data.Field<int>("INOWNER") == int.Parse(txtInventoryOwner.Text.Trim()).ToString()
```

where `INOWNER` datatype is Integer. 
Integer and String both is not accepting.

Comment: What is the value of `txtInventoryOwner.Text.Trim()`

Comment: I removed     Tostring() then too its not working. 1st time its executing. When i want to execute multiple times its showing     Specified Cast is not Valid

Comment: Can we see the updated code? from the code above, I see nothing special...

Answer (score 0):

You specified the type of INOWNER is int, but you tried to convert txtInventoryOwner.Text to text object. Try removing the ToString()

```
data.Field<int>("INOWNER") == int.Parse(txtInventoryOwner.Text.Trim());
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove your ToString():

```
   where data.Field<int>("INOWNER") == int.Parse(txtInventoryOwner.Text.Trim())
```

Answer (score 0):

You mention that data.Field("INOWNER") is of type int.

Would you expect the following to compile?

```
int myInt = data.Field<int>("INOWNER");
string myString = int.Parse(txtInventoryOwner.Text.Trim()).ToString();
bool b = myInt == myString;
```